# Set title for watch kit view

Tags: swift, watchkit, title, identifier

How do I set the title for the current view in my watch kit (swift) app programmatically?

By identifier I mean the three "hashtags"
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the title on the current Interface Controller, not a View. You just need to call `setTitle()` on the Interface Controller itself.

One feasible method, where you can set the title for your controller is the `awake(withContext:)` function.

```
class WatchController: WKInterfaceController {
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        self.setTitle("Title")
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you can call it anywhere  where you have access to the interface controller. You just have to make sure, the UI is initialized by the time you call `setTitle`, so for example you cannot call it from the `init` method of an interface controller subclass.